# How to install a german keyboard layout on an english installation?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I need to use a German keyboard on an English installation. In "add an input source" only 4 English keyboard are available. What do I need to do to? I have installed the German language pack, which I do not want use, but that also did not increase the number of available keyboards. Is ubuntu 20.04 the only Linux with only English keyboards?
Best Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 4):

Under Region and Language settings, under "Input Sources" you have to actually find the German language keyboard you're after.

There's three windows you have to go through when you hit add on the Input Sources collection.  This first one, where you hit the three dots at the bottom...

[image]

... then you have to actually hit "Other" at the bottom of the list after that...

[image]

... then FINALLY when you search the massive list for "German" select the keyboard you actually want.  (There's a lot...)

[image]